# Failed to start plugin PDF Kit. PDF loads Blank on Mac Only, IOS Fine. No change to code. Was working

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, webkit, pdfkit

With no change to code, all our apps that generate a PDF in `WKWebKit` now show a blank page. Mac only.

The apps are not designed for Mac they are iOS apps that work for iPad on M1 chip or above Macs. On iPad iPhone, PDF loads correctly

This is a recent thing across all our apps on Mac, with no updates and no changes to code and on different versions of MacOS.

Error points to a problem starting`PDFKit`

Console error:

> [u A1B17741-FA9E-41D8-B1B2-CBAAB1EBCD7E:m ]
> [com.apple.PDFKit.PDFExtensionView(1.0)] Failed to start plugin; pkd returned an error: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=4 "RBSLaunchRequest error trying to launch plugin com.apple.PDFKit.PDFExtensionView(A1B17741-FA9E-41D8-B1B2-CBAAB1EBCD7E): Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x144e6cb30 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=RBSLaunchRequest error trying to launch plugin com.apple.PDFKit.PDFExtensionView(A1B17741-FA9E-41D8-B1B2-CBAAB1EBCD7E): Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x144e6cb30 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}}
> Plugin <id: 0x135077e30; core = <[u A1B17741-FA9E-41D8-B1B2-CBAAB1EBCD7E] [com.apple.PDFKit.PDFExtensionView(1.0)],[d 412A02BE-85DD-40F3-BEE5-06EDE446E5CD] [/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/Frameworks/PDFKit.framework/PlugIns/com.apple.PDFKit.PDFExtensionView.appex]>, instance = [(null)], state = 3, useCount = 0> must have pid! Extension request will fail
> Failed to acquire assertion for plugin: <id: 0x135077e30; core = <[u A1B17741-FA9E-41D8-B1B2-CBAAB1EBCD7E] [com.apple.PDFKit.PDFExtensionView(1.0)],[d 412A02BE-85DD-40F3-BEE5-06EDE446E5CD] [/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/Frameworks/PDFKit.framework/PlugIns/com.apple.PDFKit.PDFExtensionView.appex]>, instance = [(null)], state = 3, useCount = 0> pid: 0
> Unable to acquire process assertion in beginUsing: with plugin identifier: com.apple.PDFKit.PDFExtensionView, killing plugin
> begin extension request <EXExtensionRequest: 0x600001f05a40> Request PK UUID: 5AD99490-3CE0-429F-9F9B-9AA2879FBBAA with item count 0 complete with error: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=4 "RBSLaunchRequest error trying to launch plugin com.apple.PDFKit.PDFExtensionView(A1B17741-FA9E-41D8-B1B2-CBAAB1EBCD7E): Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x144e6cb30 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=RBSLaunchRequest error trying to launch plugin com.apple.PDFKit.PDFExtensionView(A1B17741-FA9E-41D8-B1B2-CBAAB1EBCD7E): Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x144e6cb30 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}}
> PlugInKit error in beginUsing: with plugin identifier: com.apple.PDFKit.PDFExtensionView, killing plugin

An Apple issue? Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Trying to show a PDF using WKWebView in an iOS app running on macOS. This is definitely a bug.

Comment: Yes it was - fixed now on 14.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been fixed on a macOS update